# mclapply additional arguments

Tags: r, parallel-processing, lapply, mclapply

I have created a function DevCstat().

It takes the arguments: indat, mod, Covar,txtMat, PatCovar.

indat is a list, I would like to apply the function to each element of the list.

mod, Covar, txtMat, PatCovar, are objects that I would like to use for each call to the function, these do not change over the list elements.

This seems to work:

```
lapply(test, DevCstat, mod='A', Covar=Covar,txtMat=txtMat, PatCovar=PatCovar)
```

However, the parallel version does not work:

```
mclapply(test,DevCstat,mod = 'A', Covar=Covar, txtMat=txtMat, PatCovar=PatCovar, SIMPLIFY = F, mc.cores = getOption("mc.cores", numcore))
```

I get the error

```
all scheduled cores encountered errors in the user code
```

I think the problem is that mclapply is not passing the additional arguments.

Does anyone know how to correctly do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can see from the following example that `mclapply` does allow extra arguments in this way:

```
mclapply(2:4, function(i,j,k) c(i,j,k), i=1, k=5)
```

I think your problem is that `mclapply` doesn't take a `SIMPLIFY` argument, so it passes it on to your function causing the error.  You might be getting confused with `mcmapply`, which does take a `SIMPLIFY` argument.